# Launch local node server at system boot

Tags: node.js, bash, raspberry-pi, startup

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi running nextjs (node server) connected with nginx. I tried using `x-terminal-emulator ‘/usr/bin/bash -c /home/pi/Desktop/startup.sh’` but many of them didn’t recognize `/usr/bin/bash` as a directory and most of them didn’t budge to execute the script. In how many ways can I start my bash script? What is the most useful way possible?

These are the ways that I tried and the errors corresponding to them.

- contrab -e: Didn’t budge to execute the command line
- rc.local: DIdn’t budge to execute the command line
- systemd: `/usr/bin/bash` file or directory doesn’t exist.

I’ve must of been using them incorrectly. If so what is the way to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recipe allows you to launch node server at system boot. In this recipe it is assumed that you have a node server running on port 3000.

Steps

1. Add node server to the rc.local file

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

Add the following line to the rc.local file

sudo node /home/pi/node_server.js

2. Make rc.local executable

sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local

3. Reboot the system

sudo reboot

4. Verify that the server is running at boot

sudo netstat –lntp | grep 3000

This should output node server which is running on port 3000.

5. Verify that the server is accessible from remote computer

curl -i http://<ip_address>:3000